# Connecting both 3.3V and GND switch to ESP32 EN pin?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, circuit-design, reset

I am a beginner and I am trying to make my own ESP32 development board, with a switch so that I can manually reset everything. I followed a tutorial online and it did this:

[image: Schematics]

My question is, why does the EN pin (or the place circled in red) read low voltage when the switch is connected? The place circled in red should have 3.3 V running through it regardless, no?

Comment: Lucas Jiang - Hi, You said: "*I followed a tutorial online and it did this (see picture).*" From what you said, it seems the picture is copied or adapted from elsewhere. Therefore to comply with the [site rule on referencing](/help/referencing) please [edit] your question and add the webpage name and its link, for the source of the original image. || Please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules here differ from typical forums. TY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EN input is using a pull-up resistor and a pull-down switch, SW3.

- When SW3 is open the EN pin is pulled to 3.3 V by R11, a 10 kΩ resistor.
- When SW3 is closed the EN pin is connected to 0 V through the switch. R11 is still trying to pull EN high but the resistance of the switch is so much lower that it will always win!

---

From the comments:

> So essentially, if 3.3v has more current, then the EN pin reads high, if gnd has more current, then the EN pin reads low? Is there a formula that calculates the final voltage at the EN pin?

Your understanding is quite garbled. Try this:

- The EN pin is very high impedance - tens or hundreds of MΩs. It draws so little current that we can ignore it.
- The EN pin is sensitive to **voltage**, not current. The datasheet will specify the logic threshold levels for the EN pin but we can simplify and say that we'd expect something in the range of
  **0 V ≤ V<sub>EN</sub> ≤ 1.2 V** gives a logic **0** and
  **1.7 V ≤ V<sub>EN</sub> ≤ 3.3 V** gives a logic **1**.

There's no need for a formula.

- If the switch is closed V<sub>EN</sub> = 0 V and is read as a 0.
- If the switch is open V<sub>EN</sub> = 3.3 V because it is pulled high by R11 and is read as a 3.3 V. (Note 'V' for 'volt' is always capitalised.)

It so happens that when the switch is closed that about 0.33 mA will flow through R11 and the switch to ground and is "wasted". In long-life battery powered applications this might be a problem so further design work would be required to reduce the power loss.

Comment: So essentially, if 3.3v has more current, then the EN pin reads high, if gnd has more current, then the EN pin reads low? Is there a formula that calculates the final voltage at the EN pin?

Comment: Lucas Jiang, you can use Ohm's law; V=IxR.  We can assume that the pin itself is not draining any current (almost). Then, when the switch is disconnected (open) you have only R11 between the 3.3V and the pin. As there is not current flowing anywhere, I=0. So the voltage drop accross the resistor is V= 0x10K = 0, so the voltage at the pin is 3.3V - 0 = 3.3V.  When the switch is connected, GND and the pin are the same electrical point, so V=0 at the pin. And then accross the resistor you have a voltage drop of 3.3V, so I = V/R = 3.3/10K = 0.33 mA. That's the current flowing through R11 to GND.

Comment: Now I see, thank you so much!